# Firefox hangs when used with selenium

Tags: python-2.7, firefox, selenium

I am using selenium and firefox webdriver for parsing a webpage. My selenium version is 2.42.1 and firefox version is 30.0 . After a couple of clicks on 'show-more-results' button, firefox hangs. My code is written below. What could be possible edits to prevent it from hanging.

```
from random import randint
from selenium import webdriver
import time
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.flipkart.com/mobiles/pr?p%5B%5D=facets.price_range%255B%255D%3DRs.%2B2000%2Band%2BBelow&p%5B%5D=sort%3Dpopularity&sid=tyy%2C4io&ref=c3bdacf2-56b7-49d6-a8bc-91b95e6031bf")
for i in range(4):
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    time.sleep(4)
while True:
  try:
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="show-more-results"]')  
    try:
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
        time.sleep(4)
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="show-more-results"]').click()
        time.sleep(randint(7,9))
    except Exception as e:
       continue
  except Exception as d:
   break
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you've to uninstall the Skype addon/extension that is in the Firefox browser. Worked like a charm for me after I unistalled it. Try it.